# Executing two thread in parallel with one thread containing an event

Tags: c++, qt

I have two functions which has to be executed after specific interval of time. So I create two threads and each function is executed in separate threads. One of the function "**checkForEvent()**" has a Event which is waiting for an event to happen.

When the "**checkForEvent()**" function is waiting for an event the other function "**checkServer()**" is not being executed even though it is run in a separate thread.

```
dongleThread = new QThread(this);
checkDongle = new QTimer();
checkDongle->setInterval(DONGLE_CHECK_TIMER);
checkDongle->moveToThread(dongleThread);
connect(checkDongle, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkForEvent()));
connect(dongleThread, SIGNAL(started()), checkDongle, SLOT(start()));
dongleThread->start();

serverThread = new QThread(this);
checkServer = new QTimer();
checkServer->setInterval(SERVER_CHECK_TIMER);
checkServer->moveToThread(serverThread);
connect(checkServer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkServer()));
connect(serverThread, SIGNAL(started()), checkServer, SLOT(start()));
serverThread->start();

checkForEvent() //This function is waiting for an Event

checkServer()
```

How can I execute both the functions in separate threads ?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `connect` call uses the default connection type: `Qt::AutoConnection`. Here is what this means:

> Qt::AutoConnection: If the receiver lives in the thread that emits the signal, Qt::DirectConnection is used. Otherwise, Qt::QueuedConnection is used. The connection type is determined when the signal is emitted.

Here your `QTimer` and `this` are in a different thread. It means `Qt::QueuedConnection` will be used.

> Qt::QueuedConnection: The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

So your two slots are called in the thread of `this`. If one is blocking, the other one will never run.

One way of fixing the problem is having a worker object moved to its own thread. The worker object would call `checkForEvent` and emit a signal after the wait is over. This signal can be connected to `checkServer` in `this`. With this, you need only one thread. You can look at the documentation of `QThread` for more information about worker objects.